# Extending JQuery Deferred in typescript

Tags: jquery, typescript

I'm trying to extend Deferred object of JQuery. This is my code in typing.d.ts:

```
interface MyPromise<TR, TJ = any, TN = any> extends JQuery.Deferred<TR, TJ, TN> {
    cancel(func: Function);
}
```

When I build my angular project, It gives me this error: **Cannot find namespace 'JQuery'**

I had the exact same code in another project and the build was successful but in new project I get error.
Does anyone know what is the problem here?

Comment: Are you using `@types/jquery` or is `namespace JQuery` defined elsewhere?

Comment: Yes, I am using @typings/jquery.